# how to select rows based on two distinct columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
id  type        type_id cust    ip_address      datetime
395 Category    5       0       119.63.196.29   2012-11-27 00:34:21
394 Cart        812     0       84.208.217.178  2012-11-27 00:31:48
393 Cart        812     0       84.208.217.178  2012-11-27 00:31:41
392 Cart        812     0       84.208.217.178  2012-11-27 00:31:35
391 Product     812     0       84.208.217.178  2012-11-27 00:31:34
```

i want to select 4 rows, ordered by id desc, which have distinct type+type_id data.

so the result from the query would remove id 393 and 392, because type and type_id combination is already in id 394.

pseudocode: select * from table where type and type_id is distinct from resultset, order by id desc limit 4

Comment: Which of the rows with the repeated type and type ID should be preserved?  Max ID?  Min ID?  Random ID?  Some other criterion?

Comment: max id should be preserved, but if thats not possible, i can go with random id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table
where id in 
(
  select min(id)
  from table 
  group by  type, type_id 
)
order by id desc
limit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM AnonymousTable AS a1
  JOIN (SELECT type, type_id, MAX(id) AS id
          FROM AnonymousTable
         GROUP BY type, type_id
       ) AS a2
    ON a1.type = a2.type AND a1.type_id = a2.type_id AND a1.id = a2.id
```

Though, since the ID values are presumably unique, you can simplify the sub-query and subsequent join:

```
SELECT *
  FROM AnonymousTable AS a1
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
          FROM AnonymousTable
         GROUP BY type, type_id
       ) AS a2
    ON a1.id = a2.id
```

The longer form will produce the right answer even if `id` is not unique (as long as the combination of `id`, `type` and `type_id` is unique).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT MAX(id) maxid, type_id, type
   FROM table
   GROUP BY type_id, type
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.maxid AND t1.type = t2.type AND t1.type_id = t2.type_id
ORDER BY t1.id desc 
LMIT 4;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94b83/1)